# Java Swing GUI -how to have a thread to be sleeping all time and be awaken by a click?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

sorry but it's the first time i use Threads.

i want Parlami class thread to sleep and be awaken only by the actionListener.

I tried this way but it isn't working, he still sleeps.
Is it right to use thread this way or should i use wait() ?

```
package parlami;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author giacomofava
 */
public class Parlami
{
    public boolean finito = false;
    public String s="";

    public void ascolta()
    {
        int i=0;
        while (i<=1500)
        {
            // dormi 50 millisecondi 
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                i+=40;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }

            while (voce.SpeechInterface.getRecognizerQueueSize() > 0)
            {
                s = s+"\n"+voce.SpeechInterface.popRecognizedString();
            }
        }
    }

    public String scrivi()
    {
        return "Hai detto: "+s;
    }

    public void leggi()
    {
        voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize(s);
    }

    public void dormi(int milli)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("i'm sleeping");
            Thread.sleep(milli);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("i'm awake ");
            ascolta();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the gui:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    private Parlami p;
    private JPanel nord, centro;
    private JButton registra, leggi;
    private JTextArea display;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new GUI();
}

public GUI()
{
    p=new Parlami();
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents()
{
    voce.SpeechInterface.init("./lib", true, true,"./lib/gram", "vocabolario");

    // N O R D
    nord=new JPanel();
    display=new JTextArea("");
    display.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    display.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    nord.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    nord.add(display);

    // C E N T R O
    centro=new JPanel();
    registra=new JButton("tieni premuto per registrare");
    registra.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();// <-------- HERE I TRY TO AWAKE HIM
            display.setText(p.scrivi());
        }

    });

    centro.add(registra);
    leggi=new JButton("leggi");
    centro.add(leggi);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(nord, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(centro, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setSize(700,300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    p.dormi(50000);  // <-------- HERE I TELL HIM TO SLEEP

}
}
```

Comment: Instead o`Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`, have you tried p.interrupt()?  `Parlami` should also be a seperate thread (i.e. by implementing Runnable).  Also, I notice it is only sleeping for 40ms anyway; I would use wait/notify.

Comment: You'll want to do some research into "locks", maybe start with [Lock Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html), the idea is you "wait" on the lock in one thread and, using the same instance of the lock, "notify" monitors that some update has occured that they should then process.  Remember though, Swing is single threaded, you should never perform any action on the EDT which might block it (like waiting on a lock object) and you should only update the UI from within the EDT

Comment: yes i have already tried with parlami.interrupt() :(

Comment: The question I have is, why?  You have an `ActionListener`, surely that can call some method to perform the required action, why do you need the thread?

Answer (score 5):

If you call `Thread.sleep` on the Swing event thread, you will put the entire application to sleep rendering it useless, but more importantly, there's no need to do this. You simply have the ActionListener activate whichever object needs activation as this is how event-driven programming works.

If you need a delay in a Swing application, use a Swing Timer, something that has been discussed over and over again on this site.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic concept of thread wait/notify associated with the topic of thread locks.  Basically, you have some common object which is acting as the "lock", one thread "waits" on this thread and when another thread needs to, it "notifies" the monitors that some action has occurred to which they should/can respond.

It'd start by having a look at [Lock Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) for more details.

Below is a very basic example of the concept, a `Thread` is allowed to run continuously, but which "waits" on the common lock.  The `ActionListener` of the button "notifies" the lock when it is pressed, allowing the `Thread` to continue working until, once again, blocks at the "wait"

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runner());
                t.start();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("Press me");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    synchronized (LOCK) {
                        LOCK.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            });
            add(btn);
        }

    }

    public class Runner implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                synchronized (LOCK) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Nothing to see here, just waiting");
                        LOCK.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Look at me, I'm busy");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Remember, Swing is single threaded, never perform any action which is blocking within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, equally, never update the UI from outside the EDT.

If you need to update the UI for some reason from the other thread, then I suggest you have a look at `SwingWorker`, which will make your life much simpler.  See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.

You have an `ActionListener` which is notified when the button is activated, why do you need a monitor lock to perform the associated action? Does it take a noticeable amount of time to start the required action?  You could just start a new thread when the button is clicked.

If you're waiting for some kind of timeout, then, to be honest, a Swing `Timer` is probably more suited to the task

Comment: Thanks i'll try! yes it takes a lot of time to start the required action.